# How can I return all previous items in a JavaScript array than a current value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Let's say I have an array:

```
var myArr = new Array('alpha','beta','gamma','delta');
```

And that I want a function to return an array of all items before a given item:

```
function getAllBefore(current) {
    var myArr = new Array('alpha','beta','gamma','delta');
    var newArr = ???
    return newArr;
}

getAllBefore('beta'); // returns Array('alpha');
getAllBefore('delta'); // returns Array('alpha','beta','gamma');
```

What's the fastest way to get this?  Can I split an array on a value?  Do I have to loop each one and build a new array on the fly?  What do you recommend?

What about if I wanted the opposite, i.e. `getAllAfter()`?

Comment: Use `indexOf` to get the position of the first item that matches what you're looking for. Then use `slice` from 0 to that index

Comment: Use `.indexOf()` to find the match and `.slice()` to make a copy of part of the array.

Comment: No need for slice, just set the length to the index + 1 (as long as modifying the original is OK). :-) Also, Array.prototype.indexOf is ES5 so may need extra support for older browsers.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
function getAllBefore(current) {
    var myArr = new Array('alpha','beta','gamma','delta');
    var i = myArr.indexOf(current);
    return i > -1 ? myArr.slice(0, i) : [];
}
```

Get the index of the specified item. If found, [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) from 0 to that index. If not found, return an empty array (or whatever other default value you like).

Note that `.indexOf()` is not supported (for arrays) in IE8 and older, but there is [a shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility) you can use, or you could just use a simple `for` loop instead.

Comment: Thanks!  What would I change to get `getAllAfter(current)`?

Comment: @Ryan `myArr.slice(i + 1)`

Comment: All after? `return i > -1 ? myArr.slice(i+1) : myArr.slice(0);` - that is, return from 1 after the index if the item is found, otherwise return a copy of the whole array if not found (or whatever other default you want for when not found; you could use `return i > -1 ? myArr.slice(i+1) : [];` to default to an empty array).

Comment: +1 for using ternary operators... I rarely see them in javascript and although some people hate then, for a simple either/or, I find it much easier to read.

Comment: There's a missing requirement: if *current* isn't found, should it return the entire array or an empty array? Assuming the latter, the last line can be `return myArr.slice(0, i < 0? 0 : i);`.

Comment: @RobG - Yes, that requirement hasn't been spelled out, but I covered those options in my previous comment and in my answer. I don't really like using `.slice(0, i<0 ? 0 : i)` because it seems kind of a waste to use `.slice()` to return an empty array. Doing it as shown in my answer looks clearer to me, and also allows an easy change to return `null` or `undefined` should the requirement change...

Answer (score 2):

javascript slice array

```
// array.slice(start, end)
const FRUITS = ["Banana", "Orange", "Lemon", "Apple", "Mango"];
var citrus = FRUITS.slice(1, 3);
// citrus => [ 'Orange', 'Lemon' ]

// Negative values slice in the opposite direction
var fromTheEnd = FRUITS.slice(-3, -1);
// fromTheEnd => [ 'Lemon', 'Apple' ]
```

array cut only last 5 element

```
 arr.slice(Math.max(arr.length - 5, 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `indexOf` and [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
newArr = myArr.slice(0, myArr.indexOf(current));
```

Comment: what abount index of returning -1?

Comment: @PilgerstorferFranz no worries there, it would just return an empty array.

Comment: @McGarnagle: No, it returns everything but the last element then.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had to do something like this for an array of objects. This is what I went with:

```
const myArr = [
    { controlId: 1, value: 'alpha'},
    { controlId: 2, value: 'beta' },
    { controlId: 3, value: 'gamma' },
    { controlId: 4, value: 'delta'}
];

function getAllBefore(id) {
    const index = myArr.findIndex( ({ controlId }) => controlId === id);
    return myArr.filter((_, i) => i < index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
var index = myArr.indexOf('beta');
var before = myArray.slice(0, index);
```